# led SMPS converter

Tags: led, switch-mode-power-supply, design, led-driver, efficiency

Which type of converter is best for an LED light for getting better efficiency and high colour rendering index? We want to design a converter up to 80 Watts which gives indirect lighting and less shadow effect.

Please suggest which SMPS converter is best suitable.

Comment: Details of the LED and power supply are needed to answer this. Be careful not to ask directly for product recommendations as these are off-topic for questions.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the power supply DESIGN is correct, the type of converter has minimal affect on LED performance as long as it meets the specification.

Please advise:
 - Supply voltage,
 - LED type (datasheet link or at least voltage?current and
 - Light output
 - Desired ambient and LED Operating temperature. 
 - As much other technical detail as possible.

High CRI (colour rendering index) is a function of the LED and operating it under properly specified conditions.

The meaning of "Indirect lighting" is unclear in this context, but optical affects relating to light distribution, shadows etc are functions of the LED optical design and surrounding optical  modifiers such as lenses, reflectors, diffusers etc.

Energy conversion efficiency is a function of the lED characteristics, operating point and, finally, the converter.

To maximise converter efficiency you need to know Vsupply characteristics and the desired LED characteristics (voltage, current, temperature, data sheet information on CRI factors, ...).

Proper operation of LEDs requires that they be fed from a constant current supply, with the LED operating at a forward voltage that matches the supplied current. Almost any converter can be controlled so as to provide a constant current supply.
An 80 Watt LED lamp will usually consist of multiple LEDs - usually in series to allow ease of constant current driving. For best LED performance the supply should have low noise and maintain the designed current.